# Infusionsoft contact list with Python

Tags: python-3.x, xml-rpc, infusionsoft

Just wondered if anyone could help. I have tried different ways to query my contacts in Infusionsoft using Python to no avail. I have managed to connect to the server, add contacts and amend fields but I am having trouble listing all my contacts and their Phone1 and Phone2 numbers. Could anyone point me in the right direction regarding the code below? I know it will need some tweaking! Your help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import xmlrpc.client
server = 
xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy("https://xxxxx.infusionsoft.com:443/api/xmlrpc");

key = "xxxxxx";

print ("Welcome! You are now connected to: ", server);

table = 'Contact'
returnFields = ['Id', 'FirstName', 'Phone1', 'Phone2']
query = {'FirstName', 'Phone1', 'Phone2'}
limit = 10
page = 0
results = server.system('query', table, limit, page, query, returnFields)

for result in results: 
   print ('Found: '), result['FirstName','Phone1', 'Phone2'];
```

Answer (score 0):

If result is a dictionary, and it probably is, you can access the info you are looking for like this :

```
for result in results:
    print("Found: {},{},{}".format(result['FirstName'], result['Phone1'], result['Phone2']))
```

Comment: Thank you Antoine. I have tried your suggestion and I got the following error:

Comment: ...File "C:\Users\TTG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\xmlrpc\client.py", line 971, in dumps
    data = m.dumps(params)
  File "C:\Users\TTG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\xmlrpc\client.py", line 502, in dumps
    dump(v, write)
  File "C:\Users\TTG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\xmlrpc\client.py", line 514, in __dump
    raise TypeError("cannot marshal %s objects" % type(value))
TypeError: cannot marshal <class 'set'> objects